# liquibase generateChangeLog changelogSchemaName

Tags: liquibase

Is it possible to generate change log using generateChangeLog command for non default user schema. I've tried to do it using  defaultSchemaName argument but it it didn't worked out. Liquibase is throwing
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use default schema name myschema on M
icrosoft SQL Server because the login schema of the current user (dbo) is different and MSSQL does not support setting the default schema per session.

I've also tried to use maven plugin but only dbo schema has been dumped. Plugin configuration looks like follows:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>                  
            <propertyFile>src/main/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            <changelogSchemaName>mySchema</changelogSchemaName>
            <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
        </configuration>                
    </plugin>
```

Comment: as far as I can see, `changelogSchemaName` property doesn't work. I was able to change `liquibase.databaseChangeLogLockTableName` but not the changelog schema name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to get liquibase-maven-plugin to process a different schema via the property defaultSchemaName, which I put into a liquibase.properties file, referenced from the POM.

```
defaultSchemaName: EXAMPLE
```

I tried other properties with no luck.